# Kafka not able to connect with zookeeper with error "Timed out waiting for connection while in state: CONNECTING"

Tags: docker, kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to run my kafka and zookeeper in kubernetes pods.

Here is my `zookeeper-service.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert
    kompose.version: 1.1.0 (36652f6)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: zookeeper-svc
  name: zookeeper-svc
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "2181"
    port: 2181
    targetPort: 2181
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: zookeeper
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Below is `zookeeper-deployment.yaml`

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert
    kompose.version: 1.1.0 (36652f6)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: zookeeper
  name: zookeeper
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: zookeeper
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
        name: zookeeper
        ports:
        - containerPort: 2181
        resources: {}
      restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
```

`kafka-deployment.yaml` is as below:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml
    kompose.version: 1.1.0 (36652f6)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: kafka
  name: kafka
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: kafka
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME
          value: kafka
        - name: KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT
          value: zookeeper:2181
        - name: KAFKA_PORT
          value: "9092"
        - name: KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MS
          value: "60000"
        image: wurstmeister/kafka
        name: kafka
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9092
        resources: {}
      restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
```

I first start the zookeeper service and deployment. Once the zookeeper is started and `kubectl get pods` shows it in running state, I start kafka deployment. Kafka deployment starts failing and restarting again and again, due to restartPolicy as always. When I checked the logs from kafka docker, I found that it is not able to connect to zookeeper service and the connection timesout. Here are the logs from kafka container.

```
[2018-09-03 07:06:06,670] ERROR Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClientTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for connection while in state: CONNECTING
atkafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient$$anonfun$kafka$zookeeper$ZooKeeperClient$$ waitUntilConnected$1.apply$mcV$sp(ZooKeeperClient.scala:230)
at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient$$anonfun$kafka$zookeeper$ZooKeeperClient$$waitUntilConnected$1.apply(ZooKeeperClient.scala:226)
at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient$$anonfun$kafka$zookeeper$ZooKeeperClient$$waitUntilConnected$1.apply(ZooKeeperClient.scala:226)
at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inLock(CoreUtils.scala:251)
at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.kafka$zookeeper$ZooKeeperClient$$waitUntilConnected(ZooKeeperClient.scala:226)
at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.<init>(ZooKeeperClient.scala:95)
at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$.apply(KafkaZkClient.scala:1580)
at kafka.server.KafkaServer.kafka$server$KafkaServer$$createZkClient$1(KafkaServer.scala:348)
at kafka.server.KafkaServer.initZkClient(KafkaServer.scala:372)
at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:202)
at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:38)
at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:75)
at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
[2018-09-03 07:06:06,671] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2018-09-03 07:06:06,673] WARN  (kafka.utils.CoreUtils$)
java.lang.NullPointerException
atkafka.server.KafkaServer$$anonfun$shutdown$5.apply$mcV$sp(KafkaServer.scala:579)
at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.swallow(CoreUtils.scala:86)
at kafka.server.KafkaServer.shutdown(KafkaServer.scala:579)
at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:329)
at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:38)
at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:75)
at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
[2018-09-03 07:06:06,676] INFO shut down completed 
(kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2018-09-03 07:06:06,677] ERROR Exiting Kafka. 
(kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable)
[2018-09-03 07:06:06,678] INFO shutting down 
(kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

What could be the reason for this ? and solutions ?

Edit: logs from zookeeper pod:

```
2018-09-03 10:32:39,562 [myid:] - INFO  
[main:ZooKeeperServerMain@96] - Starting server
2018-09-03 10:32:39,567 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - 
Server environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.9-1757313, built on 
08/23/2016 06:50 GMT
2018-09-03 10:32:39,567 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - 
Server environment:host.name=zookeeper-7594d99b-sgm6p
2018-09-03 10:32:39,567 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - 
Server environment:java.version=1.7.0_65
2018-09-03 10:32:39,567 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - 
Server environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
2018-09-03 10:32:39,567 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - 
Server environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
2018-09-03 10:32:39,567 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - 
Server environment:java.class.path=/opt/zookeeper- 
3.4.9/bin/../build/classes:/opt/zookeeper- 
3.4.9/bin/../build/lib/*.jar:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.9/bin/../lib/slf4j- 
log4j12-1.6.1.jar:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.9/bin/../lib/slf4j-api-1.6. 
1.ja r:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.9/bin/../lib/netty- 
3.10.5.Final.jar:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.9/bin/../lib/log4j- 
1.2.16.jar:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.9/bin/../lib/jline- 
0.9.94.jar:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.9/bin/../zookeeper- 
3.4.9.jar:/opt/zookeeper- 
3.4.9/bin/../src/java/lib/*.jar:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.9/bin/../conf:

2018-09-03 10:32:39,567 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - 
Server environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
2018-09-03 10:32:39,569 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - 
Server environment:java.compiler=<NA>
2018-09-03 10:32:39,569 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - 
Server environment:os.name=Linux
2018-09-03 10:32:39,569 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - 
Server environment:os.arch=amd64 
2018-09-03 10:32:39,569 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - 
Server environment:os.version=4.15.0-20-generic
2018-09-03 10:32:39,569 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] -     
Server environment:user.name=root
2018-09-03 10:32:39,569 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - 
Server environment:user.home=/root
2018-09-03 10:32:39,569 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - 
Server environment:user.dir=/opt/zookeeper-3.4.9
2018-09-03 10:32:39,570 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServer@815] 
- 
tickTime set to 2000
2018-09-03 10:32:39,571 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServer@824] 
- 
minSessionTimeout set to -1
2018-09-03 10:32:39,571 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServer@833] 
- 
maxSessionTimeout set to -1
2018-09-03 10:32:39,578 [myid:] - INFO  
[main:NIOServerCnxnFactory@89] 
- binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181
```

Edit:
starting logs from kafka container:

```
Excluding KAFKA_HOME from broker config
[Configuring] 'advertised.host.name' in 
'/opt/kafka/config/server.properties'
[Configuring] 'port' in '/opt/kafka/config/server.properties'
[Configuring] 'broker.id' in '/opt/kafka/config/server.properties'
Excluding KAFKA_VERSION from broker config
[Configuring] 'zookeeper.connect' in 
'/opt/kafka/config/server.properties'
[Configuring] 'log.dirs' in '/opt/kafka/config/server.properties'
[Configuring] 'zookeeper.connect.timeout.ms' in 
'/opt/kafka/config/server.properties'
 [2018-09-05 10:47:22,036] INFO Registered 
kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean 
(kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$) 
[2018-09-05 10:47:23,145] INFO starting (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2018-09-05 10:47:23,148] INFO Connecting to zookeeper on 
zookeeper:2181 (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2018-09-05 10:47:23,288] INFO [ZooKeeperClient] Initializing a new 
session to zookeeper:2181. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2018-09-05 10:47:23,300] INFO Client 
environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.13- 
2d71af4dbe22557fda74f9a9b4309b15a7487f03, built on 06/29/2018 00:39 
GMT (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2018-09-05 10:47:23,300] INFO Client environment:host.name=kafka 
-757dc6c47b-zpzfz (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2018-09-05 10:47:23,300] INFO Client 
environment:java.version=1.8.0_171 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2018-09-05 10:47:23,301] INFO Client 
environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation 
(org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2018-09-05 10:47:23,301] INFO Client 
environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre 
(org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2018-09-05 10:47:23,301] INFO Client 
environment:java.class.path=/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/activation- 
1.1.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/aopalliance-repackaged-2.5.0- 
b42.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/argparse4j- 
0.7.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/audience-annotations- 
0.5.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/commons-lang3- 
3.5.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-api- 
2.0.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-basic-auth-extension- 
2.0.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-file- 
2.0.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-json- 
2.0.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-runtime- 
2.0.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-transforms- 
2.0.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/guava- 
20.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/hk2-api-2.5.0- 
b42.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/hk2-locator-2.5.0- 
b42.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/hk2-utils-2.5.0- 
b42.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-annotations- 
2.9.6.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-core- 
2.9.6.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-databind- 
2.9.6.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider- 
2.9.6.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations- 
CR2.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/javax.annotation-api- 
1.2.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/javax.inject- 
1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/javax.inject-2.5.0- 
b42.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/javax.servlet-api- 
3.1.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/javax.ws.rs-api- 
2.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jaxb-api- 
2.3.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-client- 
2.27.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-common- 
2.27.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-container-servlet 
-2.27.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-container-servlet-core- 
2.27.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-hk2- 
2.27.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-media-jaxb- 
2.27.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-server 
-2.27.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-client 
-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-continuation- 
9.4.11.v20180605.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-http- 
9.4.11.v20180605.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-io- 
9.4.11.v20180605.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-security- 
9.4.11.v20180605.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-server- 
9.4.11.v20180605.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-servlet- 
9.4.11.v20180605.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-servlets- 
9.4.11.v20180605.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-util- 
9.4.11.v20180605.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jopt-simple- 
5.0.4.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-clients- 
2.0.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-log4j-appender- 
2.0.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-streams- 
2.0.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-examples- 
2.0.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-scala_2.11- 
2.0.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-test-utils- 
2.0.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-tools- 
2.0.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka_2.11-2.0.0- 
sources.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka_2.11-2 
 .0.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/log4j 
1.2.17.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/lz4-java- 
1.4.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/maven-artifact- 
3.5.3.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/metrics-core- 
2.2.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/osgi-resource-locator- 
1.0.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/plexus-utils- 
3.1.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/reflections- 
0.9.11.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/rocksdbjni- 
5.7.3.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/scala-library- 
2.11.12.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/scala-logging_2.11- 
3.9.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/scala-reflect- 
2.11.12.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/slf4j-api- 
1.7.25.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/slf4j-log4j12- 
1.7.25.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/snappy-java- 
1.1.7.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/validation-api- 
1.1.0.Final.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/zkclient- 
0.10.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/zookeeper-3.4.13.jar 
(org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
```

output for `kubectl get svc -o wide` is as follows:

```
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE       SELECTOR
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP    50m       <none>
zookeeper    ClusterIP   10.98.180.138   <none>        2181/TCP   48m       io.kompose.service=zookeeper
```

output from `kubectl get pods -o wide`:

```
NAME                       READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE       IP           NODE
kafka-757dc6c47b-zpzfz     0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   15         1h        10.32.0.17   administrator-thinkpad-l480
zookeeper-7594d99b-784n9   1/1       Running            0          1h        10.32.0.19   administrator-thinkpad-l480
```

Edit:
output from `kubectl describe pod kafka-757dc6c47b-zpzfz`:

```
Name:           kafka-757dc6c47b-zpzfz
Namespace:      default
Node:           administrator-thinkpad-l480/10.11.17.86
Start Time:     Wed, 05 Sep 2018 16:17:06 +0530
Labels:         io.kompose.service=kafka
            pod-template-hash=3138727036
Annotations:    <none>
Status:         Running
IP:             10.32.0.17
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/kafka-757dc6c47b
Containers:
  kafka:
   Container ID:docker://2bdc06d876ae23437c61f4e95539a67903cdb61e88fd9c68377b47c7705293a3
    Image:          wurstmeister/kafka
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://wurstmeister/kafka@sha256:2e3ff64e70ea983530f590282f36991c0a1b105350510f53cc3d1a0279b83c28
    Port:           9092/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Wed, 05 Sep 2018 17:29:06 +0530
      Finished:     Wed, 05 Sep 2018 17:29:14 +0530
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  18
    Environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME:          kafka
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT:             zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_PORT:                          9092
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MS:  160000
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-nhb9z (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  default-token-nhb9z:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-nhb9z
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason   Age                From                                  Message
  ----     ------   ----               ----                                  -------
  Warning  BackOff  3m (x293 over 1h)  kubelet, administrator-thinkpad-l480  Back-off restarting failed container
```

Comment: What do the zookeeper logs report?

Comment: updated the question with zookeeper logs

Comment: Zookeeper is fine... Have you tried using Confluent Helm Charts?

Comment: @cricket_007 no i didnt use helm charts..since i never heard of it( i am new to kubernetes also). But a short overview gives the hint that it has it's own kafka image.. which i dont want to use anyways. Any other way for it ?

Comment: Well, Confluent is the enterprise company and primary developers for Kafka, so I'm not sure what you have against their Kafka images

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> What could be the reason for this ? and solutions ?

The reason is hidden behind following log line:

```
INFO Connecting to zookeeper on zookeeper:2181 (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

Kafka is searching for `zookeeper` while it should search for your service name which is `zookeeper-svc`.

The solution is then straightforward: to either rename your zookeeper service from `zookeeper-svc` to `zookeeper` in your `zookeeper-service.yaml` like so:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert
    kompose.version: 1.1.0 (36652f6)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: zookeeper
  name: zookeeper
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "2181"
    port: 2181
    targetPort: 2181
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: zookeeper
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

or, more clean, to keep service name as it is and reconfigure Kafka to search for `zookeeper-svc` instead of `zookeeper`.

**Note**: since your minimal example was enough to reproduce the issue (thank you, it is nice to see working minimal example!), although pod is up and running (not in error state) it still shows: `java.io.IOException: Can't resolve address: kafka:9092` which is tied to another issue (service not covering Kafka deployment) and is out of the scope of this question, just to let you know.

Comment: I tried after changing the `zookeeper-svc` to `zookeeper`, but still facing the same error.

Comment: Strange. I've run your exact manifests, with only renamed service (from answer) on docker edge and it started correctly and is up and running for 2h+ (error in Note is listed from log there). Are you sure you recreated correctly service manifest? Can you make sure you have right manifests and right creation order? Can you get helper container just to verify that zookeeper:2181 is reachable, up and running?

Comment: Actually, to be correct: 1) I've run your exact manifest to reproduce error. 2) I've deleted zookeeper-service, then 3) edited it to replace zookeeper-svc with zookeeper on both places, 4) recreated service and 5) deleted and created kafka-deployment. After those exact steps all is still up and running...

Comment: i have followed the same steps, still facing the same issue. And, what do you mean by getting helper container to verify that zookeeper:2181 is reachable ?

Comment: Start up any other container (busybox or whatever) in same namespace, and then exec to it to verify you can access zookeeper:2181 from there. Connection issue is indicative that you can't reach desired host, and this was initially service related, just make sure you have that covered and that within cluster you are good with zookeeper host.

Comment: can you post beginning of the kafka container log as well, to make sure we are on the same page with configuration and connection?

Comment: yes, you are running against proper name and port: `INFO Connecting to zookeeper on zookeeper:2181`. Now can post output of your services as well `kubectl get svc -o wide`?

Comment: Below is the output for kubect get svc -o wide 
```
    NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE       SELECTOR
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP    50m       <none>
zookeeper    ClusterIP   10.98.180.138   <none>        2181/TCP   48m       io.kompose.service=zookeeper
```

Comment: and can you update with `kubectl get pods -o wide` and show relevant zookeeper and kafka pods only?

Comment: and can you share `kubectl describe pod kafka-757dc6c47b-zpzfz` ?

Comment: added the result

Comment: Can you verify that service is up and reachable with following two commands: get endpoints with `kubectl get ep` and then execute `kubectl run -it --rm test --image=busybox --restart=Never -- sh` to run test pod and when within that pod type `nslookup zookeeper` to check DNS is working correctly. Then try if port is actually open `nc -zv zookeeper 2181`. Once you exit test pod it will automatically remove itself. Make sure that you can see zookeeper and that port is open.

Comment: When i do a nslookup from the test pod, i see the error msg as `connection timed out; no servers could be reached`.  SO i guess DNS is not working well. How do i fix this ?

Comment: Yes, looks like DNS issue, can you check following nslookups as well while you are at it: `nskookup kubernetes` and `nslookup test` those should give you presumably kubernetes service and own temporary busy box test pod. If you don't se either then you have serious network misconfiguration within cluster. If, however, you see them resolving, then some order of resource creation might be in place (or misconfiguration, make sure that you use exactly manifests like above). In latter case I'd delete all deployments and service, create zookeeper svc,dep and kafka dep last.

Comment: I am getting the same error as connection timed out when i do nslookup for kubernetes and test.

Comment: i am going to do a fresh setup and proper network configuration, and try the above steps again. Will revert back here again with the results/errors.

Comment: Ok, just check do you have kube-dns up and running and what is your CNI..

Comment: i was using weave-net for my cni plugin.

Comment: it was indeed a problem with kube-dns. now that my kube-dns setup is correct, I can do nslookup for all the services and kafka is also able to connect to zookeeper. Thank you for the help and pointing at the correct issue.

Comment: Sure, glad that it was resolved! Can you please, mark answer as accepted and upvote in line with [SO guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for answers. Thanks!

Comment: @LakshyaGarg Hi, how can you correct your dns setup? I have same problem!

Answer (score 9):

In my case I was trying to start Kafka server before starting the Zookeeper.

So correct order is to start Zookeeper and then Kafka server.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue while running atlas with zookeeper docker image.
Increasing timeout helped me.

```
atlas.kafka.zookeeper.session.timeout.ms=40000
atlas.kafka.zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=20000
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using microk8s with this warning

> WARNING:  IPtables FORWARD policy is DROP

Consider enabling traffic forwarding with:

`sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT`

fixing it worked for me